# Mlflow Experiment_ID starts at unique ID instead of 1

Tags: python, mlflow

When I create an experiment, instead of having an experiment_id of 1, it starts with a random uid like
797908870096427845. Is there any reason for this? I somehow cannot even replicate their docs of having experiment_id of 1

Example Documentation Output

```
Name: Social NLP Experiments
Experiment_id: 1
Artifact Location: file:///.../mlruns
Tags: {'version': 'v1', 'priority': 'P1'}
Lifecycle_stage: active
Creation timestamp: 1662004217511
```

My Output:

```
Experiment: artifact_location='path', creation_time=1702468361549, experiment_id='590721806021003990', last_update_time=1702468361549, lifecycle_stage='active', name='test', tags={}
```

This is hard for my team to refer to which experiment ID when traverse through the folder structure as it uses the ID as the folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is likely by design in the MLflow system. While the specific rationale may depend on the implementation details of MLflow, there are some common reasons why system designers might choose to use non-sequential or random IDs:

- Scalability: Random or non-sequential IDs can be easier to generate and manage in distributed and scalable systems.
- Uniqueness: Random or hashed IDs are less prone to collisions.
- Decentralization: In scenarios where multiple instances or services can independently create experiments or entities